# where to place the out-file cmdlet ?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, file-io, powershell-4.0

I was doing a small script in the past which searches for big files in a specific location. Now I want to create a .txt file with my result. But unfortunately I didn't manage to place the cmdlet correctly. I outfiled other things but, here I have some trouble.

```
get-childitem  "c:\projects" -recurse | where {$_.length -gt 50mb } | foreach-object {write-host $_.FullName  ("{0:N2}" -f ($_.Length / 1MB)) "MB" -ForegroundColor "green" }
```

I tried too tee the object and outfile the varible, I tried to put the out-file in the end and i tried to put it before I format the size.

It was only working when I placed it before the formatting. But I'd love to have formatted sizes in my .txt  , on the other places it just created a blank .txt file.

Comment: i don't need the color , the font size is always the same. the formatting just formats the bytes to mb.

Answer (score 2):

here is one method, uses `Add-Content` with -Encoding String to append data.  Also plopped your formatted sizes into a variable, so we could pass them around avoiding the pipeline object and allowing us to remain green in the console.

```
get-childitem  "C:\projects" -recurse | where {$_.length -gt 50mb } | foreach-object {$a = $_.FullName + " " + ("{0:N2}" -f ($_.Length / 1MB)) + "MB" ; write-host $A -ForegroundColor "green";Add-Content -Path C:\text.txt -Value "$a" -Encoding String}
#
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Get-ChildItem  "c:\projects" -recurse | 
    where {$_.length -gt 50mb } | 
    select FullName, @{Name="MB";Expression={("{0:N2}" -f ($_.Length / 1MB))}} | 
    Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize | 
    Out-File -FilePath size.txt -Append
```

I dropped the foreground color as you won't be able to output that, and added Format-Table -AutoSize to fix long path truncation.

Comment: upon testing, this one truncates extra long paths, leaving something like `C:\projects\superlongfoldername\subfolder\toolong.....` in the output.  I could not override with the out-file `-Width 255` paramater.

Comment: @Knuckle-Dragger I added Format-Table to fix truncation. Not sure how long of a path that will support though.

Comment: Good catch beavel, forgot all about that.  Upon searching I found this post which reminded me we must use `Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize` for insanely long outputs.        http://superuser.com/questions/690239/powershell-env-avoid-truncation-of-environment-variables